# How to delete file from aws s3bucket android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using these dependencies for aws s3bucket operations in android and
it's working for file upload, but it's not working for file delete.

```
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar') { transitive = true }

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.+'
```

Comment: Please share us some code.

Comment: IAM permission issue?

Comment: Can you please share some code and share error stack trace if any?
Also please use the latest version 2.16.5 of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, objectName));
```

Here the bucketName is your aws s3 bucket's name and objectName is your File name as in the s3 storage and remember in s3 storage the  file name are as per the paths not just the names.

Answer (score 0):

Works Good Just run on a new Thread

```java
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, objectName));
                    }
                }).start();
```